# Applescript to input text in website

Tags: automation, applescript, copy-paste, paste

```
set query to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Query" default answer "" buttons {"Input", "Cancel"} default button 1)

open location "http://www.soundcloud.com/"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    key code 48
end tell
delay 1
query
```

So i'm trying to make an applescript that:

1) Prompts with dialogue box to enter data

2) Opens up webpage

3) Presses tab to get to first text box

4) Pastes data from step 1

**I've figured out how to get to up to step 4 but when i print the query variable it only prints it within the applescript not the webpage.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set query to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Query" default answer "" buttons {"Input", "Cancel"} default button 1)

open location "http://www.soundcloud.com/"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    key code 48
    delay 1
    keystroke query
end tell
```

I needed to add keystroke into the commandline

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
set query to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Query" default answer "" buttons {"Input", "Cancel"} default button 1)

tell application "Safari"
    if not (exists document 1) then reopen
    activate
    set URL of document 1 to "http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at/cgi-bin/RNAfold.cgi"
    delay 3
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByName('SCREEN')[0].value=" & quoted form of query & "" in document 1
end tell
```